# Qt's iterators - are they all const?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm doing:
 `QMap<QString,Qt::CheckState>::iterator beg = data_.begin();//here data_ is of type  QMap<QString,Qt::CheckState>`
 and qt tells me:
 error: conversion from 'QMap::const_iterator' to non-scalar type 'QMap::iterator' requested

Why? I didn't asked for cbegin, so what's the story with this?

Comment: What is `data_` -- is it `const`?

Comment: Sounds like `data_` is const at this point in time, so the const version of `begin()` will be called.

Comment: @KerrekSB && Moo-Juice fair play, that's it. Thanks guys. One of you can post it as an answer so I could accept it. Anyway +1 for both of ya;

Comment: There're two types of iterators. Java-like iterator and C++ style iterator. I think you should read about their differences and how to use them correctly(there is great article in book named "C++  GUI Programming with Qt 4 (2nd Edition)" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `data_` is `const` at this point in time, so the `const` version of `begin()` will be called. :)